# Adding a class to option elements using the Rails 3 form helpers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Right now I have a dropdown which is coded like so:

`<%= f.select(:mydropdown, [["None", "0"], ["Some", "1"], ["More", "2"]], { :include_blank => true })%>`

Is there a way to specify that each of these options should also have an associated class? So that it would output...

`<option value="0" class="none">None</option>`

This is so that I can color code various options. I *can* use CSS3 for that, but would like to have something more widely supported if possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just do this:

```
    <%= f.select(:mydropdown, options_for_select([ ["None", 0, {:class=>'none'}], ["Some", 1, {:class=>'bold'}], ["More", 2] ]), { :include_blank => true })%>
```

Ref here:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_for_select